# Conditional statement checking lines n AND n-1

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a DF with behavioral data of an experiment (emotional stroop task) with trials which are either congruent or incrongruent.
example:

```
ID |trial|Congruency |CorrectResponse|responseTime
1  | 1   | Congruent |   1           | 450
1  | 2   |InCongruent|   0           | 465
1  | 3   | Congruent |   1           | 567 
1  | 4   | Congruent |   1           | 498
2  | 1   |InCongruent|   1           | 605
2 ...
2
2
```

I would like to create a new variable in my DF called "Repetition", which will be coded as followed:

- "Yes (or actually `-0.5`) if the trial n and the trial n-1 are both congruent or are both incongruent
- "No" (or actually `0.5`) if the trial n and the trial n-1 are one congruent and one incongruent.

When I create a new variable, I usually use this (example):

```
DF <- DF %>% 
  mutate (CR = ifelse ((emotion =="FEA" & Reponse == 2) | (emotion == "NEU" & Reponse == "NaN"), -0.5, 0.5))
```

But I don't know how to use this kind of statement when I have to check conditions in two different line...

ADDITIONALY, I will have to remove the first trial of each participant (as my there is a problem with n=1 and the data of all my participants are bound)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I added a very simplified example in the question (but I have 240 trial by participant and other factors in my DF). But i can send you the complete DF if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` to get `n - 1` value :

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Repetition = ifelse(Congruency == lag(Congruency), 'Yes', 'No'))
  #Without using ifelse
  #mutate(Repetition = c('No', 'Yes')[(Congruency == lag(Congruency)) + 1])
```

This will give `NA` for first value for each `ID` which you can remove by adding `filter(!is.na(Repetition))` to the above.

If you want values to be 0.5 and -0.5 instead, you can use :

```
ifelse(Congruency == lag(Congruency), 0.5, -0.5)
```

---

In `data.table` you can use `shift` to get previous value.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[,Repetition := ifelse(Congruency == shift(Congruency), 'Yes', 'No'), ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to turn **Yes** and **No** to `-0.5` and `0.5` directly, then try this

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Repetition1 = (Congruency != lag(Congruency)) - 0.5)
```